# Wordpress PHP include using a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, include

I am trying to include template part files using a switch and include_once

```
if ( $switch == "template_1" ) 
{ include_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'path_to_template_file.php'); 
  include_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'path_to_style.php');
```

Comment: You have included the file correctly, please share more details

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.